# Why the result from modulo is NaN in R?

Tags: r, modulo

I use the following algorithm

```
q=2
t=2
x<-c(0)
x[1]<-1
z<-(x[1]*t)%%69
x[2]<-(x[1]*t)%%69
while( x[q]!=x[1] )
{
  z<-z*t
  q=q+1
  x[q]<-z%%69
}
```

and the result is the following

```
x
# [1]  1  2  4  8 16 32 64 59 49 29 58 47 25 50 31 62 55 41 13 26 52 35  1
```

which means that the algorithm works for t=2.

When I use `t=7`, I have the following error

> Error in while (x[q] != x[1]) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

because the new inputs are

```
x[q]
# [1] NaN
z
# [1] Inf
```

Also, I have warnings like this one:

> 1: probable complete loss of accuracy in modulus.

Where is the problem?

Comment: Maybe because of the result of `7^c(2:22)`, compared to `2^c(2:22)`.

Comment: your number are bursting out. In this kind of while loop, ALWAYS put a log or a print to check what's going on when you build the algo for the first time ...

Comment: I get out of the problem which Pascal mentioned by changing `z<-z*t` to `z<-x[q]*t`. So, I don't have so huge numbers. The result still the same. Now, it works also for `t=7`.

Comment: If I make the replacement `z<-z*t` to `z<-x[q]*t` I cannot replicate the error on 64-bit OS mac.